# NUNIT3-CONSOLE exclude specific test category

Tags: nunit-3.0, nunit-console

The old NUnit 2 console runner had an `/exclude` parameter to exclude tests with a specific `Category` attribute. Does anybody know if the console runner of NUnit3 supports this feature?

`.\nunit3-console.exe --help` doesn't state an exclude parameter. I only can see a `Where` parameter, can it be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description of the selection language can be found under this [link](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language). Based on that it should be possible to exclude a category via `--where "cat != YourCategoryToExclude"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSBuildTasks you can specify the same Where statement. For example:

```
<NUnit3 Assemblies="@(NUnitIntegrationAssemblies)" 
ToolPath="$(NUnitRepositoryDir)" 
OutputXmlFile="$(MSBuildStartupDirectory)\Tools\Log\NUnit.xml" 
Where="cat != DatabaseContentDependent" 
Framework="v4.0.30319" />
```